# Implement Row Limit in sql data fetch

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I want to restrict users to fetch all the data from the table. For example, If user execute, "select * from table", it will show only 100 rows, although i have millions of rows in table, so that it will not impact my production. I have more then 1000 tables in my database.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please consult basic documentation for your RDBMS and SQL generally before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `offset` to fetch the limited number of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY COL
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;    ---- here you can define any number of rows
```

Comment: plus 1 then for an ANSI solution that is also more flexible than just `top` by supporting an `offset` to get subequent batches (which I'm sure readers can infer).

Comment: How can u asked user to change the query. My question, do we have any setting in sql to restrict on rows or size?

Comment: @ManishSharma What are you asking? Do you mean you want some setting that would mean **all** queries should only return the top 100 rows? Ordered by what? In all databases, or only some? For all users, or only some? And so on, and so forth. Ultimately, your question is flawed, and you cannot decide for users what data that they request that you can discard... but rather write decent applications that offer adequate filtering, don't pull out more data than they need, don't filter in the frontend side, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-2017) functionality. This allows you to limit the used resources per user.

Comment: How can u asked user to change the query. My question, do we have any setting in sql to restrict on rows or size?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to intercept a users query (e.g. SELECT * FROM table) and replace it with e.g. SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table). There is no setting, that allows you to do that. But you can limit the system resources for a user, so that a specific user only gets e.g. 20% CPU time. This can be done with the Resource Governor.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM schema.table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get batch by batch

```
 SELECT * FROM table  ORDER BY Col
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Why `offset 1 rows`? Do you really want to skip the 1st row? Also, you said "to get batch by batch", but this only shows how to get the 1st batch... albeit without the 1st row. What would they use to get subsequent batches?

Comment: How is this different from DarkRob's answer?

Comment: I think this is not different answer